# WebCachedImageView Error res xml namespace

Tags: android, namespaces, android-resources

I try use this lib:

https://github.com/leocadiotine/WebCachedImageView

i have add this as souce lib and compile worked is Ok, but in res xml ihave error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
xmlns:app:"http://schemas.android.com/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Note the /apk/. Hope it helps!